# Issue with Serverless Deploy after Deleting Object in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a Serverless project that was successfully deployed to AWS with multiple Lambda functions and a Step Function state machine with an API Gateway event. I manually deleted the Step Function in AWS and now doing a `sls deploy` does not deploy the Step Function.

How do I get things back in sync?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’ve faced this issue with Serverless. The issue is caused by how Serverless handles, tracks, and deploys your functions and resources. When you deleted the step function/state machine you effectively changed the state of your application manually, and it is basically out of sync.

To resolve this, in your serverless.yaml file, comment out the entire step function/state machine that you manually deleted, and run `sls deploy`. When its finished uncomment the step function/state machine, and `sls deploy` again. This time it should deploy your step function/state machine again.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option that has worked for me: run `sls remove` to remove the cloudformations stack you distriupted (if its for a specific stage, run `sls remove --stage <stage_name>`). Then run an `sls deploy`, and your service should be back up and in a normal state.

Comment: Allen N, this, in theory, could and often does work, depending on how the resources are configured. It could also cause other problems, especially if the service is in production and there are many other resources in the service: imagine, for example, deleting a database, or a cache, or an S3 bucket with a full `sls remove`.  It is far more efficient and better practice to remove and redeploy a single resource that is causing you issues than to delete an entire stack of resources and re-deploy all of them.

Comment: I would amend to say that the caveat to my suggestion is that if there are critical stateful resources involved, then yes, you should not remove them. However, if that isn't the case and everything can be torn down and redeployed, then this solution works pretty seamlessly.